# Magento 2 and git, best practice for custom module development

Tags: magento2, best-practice, git

I have trouble wrapping my head around a very particular issue concerning a development setup for magento 2.

I have read a lot about using composer and git. It makes a lot of sense to NOT include the vendor directory and have each module, theme and custom project in separate repositories.

To explain my issue it is best I explain my workflow.

Currently I am working on a customer project. I installed magento and a couple of modules via composer. In addition I have my own set of custom modules I am developing while creating this project. Those modules of course reside inside the app/code folder. Some are project specific and will never be reused elsewhere. Those should be part of the project's git repository.

Others WILL be reused in other projects. Therefore I want them to have their separate repository. But since they are work in progress I cannot hook them into the project like all the other modules via composer (or can I?). It is actually the other way round, I will need to commit from this current project into the repository. And this process is likely to continue when I use those modules in other projects. These modules will continously be improved.

So what would this scenario look like? In the project's root folder I would have the main project with it's own remote repository. Let's say during the course of this project I have developed three custom modules inside app/code. How would I maintain those so they will be committed and pushed into each of their repository? Would I need to set up a repository in each of the modules folders? Would I have to cd in all of them and add/commit/push individually?

I fear I might loose oversight of the state of all the modules this way.

Let's say I finish this current project but in my next project I add new features I want in my first project as well. How would I "backport" those new features into past projects?

Practical insight welcome :)

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can add the local path to the module you'll be distributing to your `composer.json`. You can then work either in the `vendor` directory or in the path you've defined.

**Example: composer.json**

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "path",
    "url": "../../packages/my-package"
  }
],
"require": {
  "my/package": "*"
}
```

Once you're preparing the customer projects release you should ensure your module is published in a none local repository with the appropriate tags (GitHub, Packagist, Satis, etc). You can then lock down the version number in your customer project's `composer.json` and remove the `"repositories"` section for this module.

**Edit**:

Further to this, you can use the glob pattern to define paths, which really helps when building an application/library with separate components.

If you had a directory structure such as this:

```
.composer
└── packages
    ├── package-1
    │   └── composer.json
    ├── package-2
    │   └── composer.json
    ├── package-3
    │   └── composer.json
    ├── package-4
    │   └── composer.json
    └── package-5
        └── composer.json
```

then defining your local repository path as:

```
"repositories": [
      {
        "type": "path",
        "url": ".composer/packages/*"
      }
    ],
    "require": {
      "my/package-1": "*",
      "my/package-2": "*",
      "my/package-3": "*",
      "my/package-4": "*",
      "my/package-5": "*"
    }
```

Would allow you to install all those components during the development stage of a project.